# 64-bit version of Visual Studio 2010 runs in 32-bit version

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

We have installed Visual Studio 2010 64-bit version on a 64-bit operating system but in the Task Manager the image name for Visual Studio 2010 displays as `*32`. On searching in Google it seems that the display indicates Visual Studio 2010 is running on a 32-bit version, and we have the same issue we have in SQL Server 2005. The 64-bit version of .NET Framework is installed. What could be the reason of a 64-bit version of a program runs as a 32-bit version?

Answer (score 8):

There is no 64-bit version of Visual Studio 2010 (or any other version of Visual Studio, for that matter). There is a 64-bit version of the .NET Framework, but Visual Studio is a 32-bit process.

There are, however, 64-bit and 32-bit versions of SQL Server, so the version you install will dictate the version that is running. That said, SQL Server Management Studio appears to be based on the Visual Studio shell, so there is only a 32-bit version of that available.