# .NET, "Any CPU/64Bit (x64)/32Bit (x86)" Best Practices, Tips and Tricks

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit, sample

If a .NET program directly or indirectly needs to call platform dependent/native/un[managed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) code it might crash.

This 32-bit/64-bit theme came into my mind after I got a new laptop with Windows 7 64-bit installed and tried to develop with the [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database.

`System.Data.SQLite` contains managed code plus unmanaged code. There is a 32-bit version and a 64-bit. Both have the same filename, but different size, and your EXE file must use the right one.

To make it more complicated: My [Visual Studio 2010 debugger is a 32-bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341808/64-bit-version-of-vs2010-runs-in-32-bit-version), so I cannot debug when using "System.Data.SQLite-64bit" from the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)!

As .NET developers we need guidelines/know-how/best practices.

And the best place to collect this kind of information that I know of is [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/).

So please, share your ideas and known issues which could serve as best practices or guidelines to survive in the 32/64/anyCPU .NET world.

I would favor one issue/trick per "answer"
so it can be commented/updated/referenced easily.

- feel free to give several "answers".

I will share my own knowledge as answers to this question, too.

Comment: Though obviously the accepted answer provides you information on bitness of .NET projects, I want to remind you there is a purely bitness friend solution out there, called C# SQLite http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/. 100% C#. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Providing an extra "x86 only" main.exe can make life easier when native code is involved**

After reading [anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth](https://web.archive.org/web/20120128063015/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx) I realised that providing an extra "x86 only" main.exe can make life easier.

Since Windows 7 64-bit can execute x86-32-bit applications the x86-program will run on most .NET-systems
(but not on non-Intel Mono systems).

As long as the [Windows 7 64-bit Visual Studio 2010 debugger is a 32-bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341808/64-bit-version-of-vs2010-runs-in-32-bit-version) the x86 app can be debugged easily.

The x86 release has as many "any CPU" DLLs as possible except the main EXE and the CPU-specific DLLs.

For machines that cannot run x86-code or where a huge memory is required you can provide an extra "any-CPU"
EXE-version. This version requires adequate installation to ensure that right platform specific code is used.

[Visual Studio 2010 How to: Configure Projects to Target Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328%28VS.100%29.aspx) describes how to set the platform to x64. The same way you can target x86.

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page.